# Is it possible to use the same docker container for multiple websites

Tags: php, mysql, docker

until a new version of php or mysql comes out I generally always use the same setup, so at the moment I create 3 containers for every site I create:-

Site 1:-

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        image: site1
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        networks:
            - site1
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: site1
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - larastock
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - site1
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8001:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
        networks:
            - site1
networks:
    site1:
volumes:
    db_data:
```

Site 2:-

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        image: site2
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        networks:
            - site2
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: site1
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - larastock
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - site2
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8001:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
        networks:
            - site2
networks:
    site2:
volumes:
    db_data:
```

They are identical except for the network but this means I have 6 containers when really I only need 3. Is it possible to tell site 2 to use the services that site 1 created or does this go against the whole point of docker?

So what I would like is to change:-

Site 1 uses php, mysql and phpmyadmin. Site 2 uses php1, mysql1, phpmyadmin1.

to:

both site 1 and site 2 using the same container's but having their own database:-

Site 1 uses php, mysql (database site1) and phpmyadmin. Site 2 uses php, mysql (database site2) and phpmyadmin

Comment: Well, yeah it's kinda' against the point.

Comment: Why not, you can perfectly can do that.. Of course that would lead to completely different files, but that completely possible.

Comment: That's absolutely normal setup. You just need to configure both sites in the same web-server (nginx or apache). But I should point that you will not have 3 containers, but 5. 1 container (php + web-server) for both sites, 2 containers for DB, 2 more containers for phpmyadmin (monitoring each DB)